# Filter combobox: how to add "NOT filtered" option?

Tags: ms-access

In my document database, I've set up a combobox to be able to filter my documents by `ProjectID`. How can I add an "All" selection (or "NOT filtered") option?

[image: Screenshot 1]

---

**Additional info:**

Cbo Row Source:

```
 SELECT [tblProjects].ProjectID, [tblProjects].ProjectTitle, [tblProjects].ProjectNo 
 FROM tblProjects;
```

Subform Data:

```
 Link Master Fields = ProjectID
 Link Child Fields = ProjectID
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a UNION ALL and create your own record.  So, assuming you want "0" to be the value of ProjectID and ProjectNo, then you would do this:

```
 SELECT [tblProjects].ProjectID, [tblProjects].ProjectTitle, [tblProjects].ProjectNo 
 FROM tblProjects
 UNION ALL
 SELECT "0", "ALL", "0"
 FROM tblProjects;
```

If ProjectID and ProjectNo are integers, you might have to tweak that a bit and use single quotes or something

Then, you would add some code that says if ProjectID = 0 then don't add the WHERE clause, otherwise add it.